# Why use request headers for CSRF tokens?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

To send a CSRF token in an AJAX call, some sites recommend sending it in the request header.

I'm wondering why. What would be the advantage over sending it with the POST variables?

Is there a good reason to send something in the header?

Comment: Do you have an example of a site recommending such method?

Answer (score -2):

In my experience the CSFR token has always an expire time, so using a cookie become an optimal medium to set an expire time.

As described by [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Example_and_characteristics) the CSFR exploit is based on forged link/request.
Using a POST/GET param to transmit the hash allows an easier exploit. 
Instead putting the hash in the header, aka cookie (impossible to set outside the domain if DNS is not hijacked), offers a stronger protection.

Comment: Hi @AD7six I was lazy, hope you found this a concrete answer.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. The question asked is why put the token in the headers instead of submitting it as post data. You aren't addressing that at all. (the token is usually compared to something in persistent storage - if you can "just" fabricate a token, it's not a csrf token it's just a request hash)

Comment: Hi @AD7six, I missed the language :( Ty  for your observations

Comment: @AD7six, I agree your distinction between hash and token, but the wikipedia article uses the word **token** and I used it for coherence.